# Use Function in {{ }} sintax

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend

Is it possible to use a function, like toLocaleLowerCase(), inside {{ }}?
If not, is there another method to do this?

```
<div *ngFor="let item of elements| keyvalue :originalOrder" class="row mt-3">
    <label class="col-md-4 offset-md-2 my-auto">{{item.key}}:</label>
    <input type="text" class='col-md-4 my-auto' formControlName={{item.key.toLocaleLowerCase()}} value={{item.value}}/>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: did u try it, what the error when u get one?

Comment: why dont you try for yourself ?

Comment: @Sysix The error is this (error Property 'toLocaleLowerCase' does not exist on type 'number'.) the problem is that no item is of type number.

Comment: but `item.key` looks like a number :) try `item.key.toString().toLocaleLowerCase()`

Comment: What about lowercase pipe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible but only if the variable on which you are calling it is a `string`.

The code inside moustaches is plain Typescript code.

If your variable is not a string, you can use the built-in pipe `| lowercase` to automate the cast to string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in angular pipe `lowercase`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of elements| keyvalue :originalOrder" class="row mt-3">
    <label class="col-md-4 offset-md-2 my-auto">{{item.key}}:</label>
    <input type="text" class='col-md-4 my-auto' formControlName={{item.key | lowercase}} value={{item.value}}/>
</div>
```